# disable carousel mouse hover displays title

Tags: javascript, mouse, image, title, carousel

I've got a carousel with ellipse. Img are in autorotating and if you want to display an img on the back to front, I use mouseover click. Carousel shows title when img is bringToFront and when mouse hovers it

The problem is I want to disable the hover effect, so it only displays title from img bringToFront.

I have found a possible solution but it is still not the one I want.

I've added the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("img").hover(function(){

      $(this).attr("rel", $(this).attr("title"));
      $(this).removeAttr("title");

   }, function(){

      $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("rel"));
      $(this).removeAttr("rel");

   });

});
```

This code disables "title" when mouse is over the carousel, but the problem is that it disables too the "title" on the front and it won't appear unless the mouse is out from the carousel.

This code works fine for me, but I want to preserve title on the front even when the mouse is over the carousel.

So I think the easiest solution is to disable all mouse effects and only preserve mouseover click, but I do not how and this is why I'm looking for some help.

Comment: did you used any special plugin if yes share it.

Comment: Professor Cloud Carousel jQuery plugin. Although I'm not using the same procedure proposed in the page, it looks like pretty much and I'm using the same plugin. You can find more information at [link](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/carousel.htm)